# How to get total distance from lat and lng in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am saving gps sigal every 5-7 sec to database. How can I see how much distance I have traveled so far when I "sum" all the lat and lng values from database. And how can i see this resoults on daily basis?

For example. When I am tracking car on live preview I want to have a distance to be suming as live data from that day. And when I am looking for example a month kilometers for certain truck?

I was looking at [THIS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) link, but I dont know how to make it dynamically to fill data as they have data already in the array.

Can you give me some ideas and examples if you implemented the same thing already.

Why to make the wheel if it is already made :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternately, you could use the Geometry Library of the Google Maps API to do the same thing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 3,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var coordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
        new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
    ];
    console.log(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(coordinates));


  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi I get some error with word `sperical` when trying to execute your code

Comment: this is working. How can I specify region to be in kilometers?

Comment: results are in meters, so just divide by 1000

Answer (score 2):

Some trigonometry will get you there.

I wish Lat/Lng were as simple as an X/Y coordinate on a 2D surface. Unfortunately, since we live on a (very wonderful) sphere called earth, latitude and longitude refer to angles of triangles with reference to the center of earth (latitude) or imaginary lines we draw on our globe (longitude). [History stuff is neat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_longitude), but that's not the point here.

I've used the Haversine forumla for calculating distance on a sphere, which you can [read more about](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) if you'd like.

I'll just post code here for simplicity. I've written in Javascript, so that's what you get :) Given two lat/lng points A and B, then:

```
// units can be english (miles) or metric (km)
var units = "english";
function calculate_distance(a, b) {
  var R = (units == "english") ? 3958.7558 : 6371; 

  var dLat = (a.lat - b.lat) * Math.PI / 180;
  var dLon = (a.lng - b.lng) * Math.PI / 180;
  var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
          Math.cos(a.lat * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(b.lat * Math.PI / 180) * 
          Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2); 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a)); 
  return R * c;
}
```

If you apply this function iteratively between your pairs of points and sum the distance... bingo.

```
function get_distance(list_of_points) {
  if (list_of_points.length == 0) return 0;

  var sum = 0;
  var last_point = list_of_points.shift();
  while (list_of_points.length > 0) {
    var next_point = list_of_points.shift();
    sum += calculate_distance(last_point, next_point);
    last_point = next_point; 
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Comment: I must say I havent been looking lat and lng in that way. Yes what I need is to sum an array of lat and lng.

Comment: went ahead and added the function to sum the distance over a list of points :)

Comment: nice doing Andy :) one more thing... What I need to change if I want to get metric values (km)